# Using glob on a directory above current?

Tags: php, glob

Currently I have a script running to grab all the images in a directory based on ending with "154x154.jpg". Basically what I'm doing is going through a gallery directory and looking for all the thumbnails of images, which I will then output in a sliding gallery on the main page of a website.

```
<?php
// loop through the images
$count = 0;
$images = array();

foreach (glob("../../uploads/2012/05/*154x154.jpg") as $filename) {
    $images[$count] = $filename;    
    $count++;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $random = mt_rand(1, $count - 1);
    echo '<li><a class="gal_img" href="#">';    
    echo '<span class="roll"></span>';
    echo '<img class="image" src="'.$images[$random].'" height="154" width="154" alt="" />';
    echo '</a></li>';
}

?>
```

This works perfectly fine as it is, but what I need to do is be able to grab the files from within a directory above the current one. To be more specific:

image folder: http://root/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/
theme folder: http://root/wp-content/themes/theme_folder/

** EDIT **

Everything works now with the above code it executes fine, when I go directly to the file. However using it within the theme generates everything except for the filepaths in the code. Using wordpress 3.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach (glob("../images/*154x154.jpg") as $filename) {
```

### Update:

Of course, this is a relative path and only works if the file you need to include is one level up from your script's  current working directory. Solution: use an absolute path, ie. one that begins with `/`. Also, keep in mind that the absolute path is a path on the disk, not the root folder of your website.

Comment: Works, I must of been spelling something wrong before when I tried that.

Comment: @jetbeck86 You accepted this answer and then unaccepted it. Is it no longer working?

Comment: Sorry, ya well it sorta does and sorta doesn't I've edited the question. 

Wasn't really sure how to edit and have it not flagged as answered.

Comment: @jetbeck86 I think I know your problem. You're using a relative path and your script's current working directory changes as you navigate around your site. Solution: use an absolute path. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm thinking I might go another route, since the relative path actually works when I execute the script directly. I could use that to get the path to file, then some how remove the ../../ from each path and then add in the direct file path in the outputted HTML. ie.

once I get all the images paths from glob "../../uploads/2012/05/image_file.jpg" 

Then I just need to remove the ../../ and replace it with http://website.com/wp-content/ just gotta figure out how to do that now :)

Comment: Still can't get it to output it into the actually front-page.

Comment: @jetbeck86: what absolute path are you now using that is not working?

Comment: Ok so to update you on this, I figured out a work around that works quite well. I couldn't figure out how to output directly inside the wordpress page, so now what I'm doing is saving the file paths to a database and then outputting them from that database. Works quite well actually. 

Final product is: http://cscs.ca/newsite/ 

At the bottom is the photo gallery, using the above script to search  for all the thumbnails and put out random ones. 

Thanks for the help :)